# Close page within Frame in a WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-4.0

I have a window and a Frame within it. in that Frame, i open many pages which i would like to close by clicking on "Close" button ,
 the problem is the page can't see my frame i tried to write in an event a close button in a page  method
to execute  another event in a main window because it's easy on a main window  to see a frame , but it's not working. here is my code in a page

```
  private void closebt_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
     {
        var main = new MainWindow();
       main.Exitbt_PreviewKeyDown(main.Exitbt, e);

     }
```

and here is a code in a main window

```
 internal void Exitbt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
         ProjectorFrame.Content = "";
         MessageBox.Show("done");
      }
```

Although the message show but it's not close  page 
please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you create another MainWindow instance inside the closebt_MouseDown hander, but I hope the following code would helpful for you:

```
private void closebt_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow main = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
    if (main != null)
    {
        main.Exitbt_PreviewKeyDown(main.Exitbt, e);
        main.Close();
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

I supposed that the main Window object of your application is `MainWindow`, so I thought that the previous code could get your application window close.
But as you commented, `Application.Current.MainWindow` is different from `MainWindow`, and the `main` became `null`.

Therefore, I think the simple way to get the main Window object is to create the following constructor in your page class to keep the reference:

```
class YourPageClass
{
    public YourPageClass(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        main = mainWindow;
    }
    private MainWindow main;

    (snip)
}
```

Then, create this instance with passing main Window object:

```
// somewhere in MainWindow code where instantiate your page object
var page = new YourPageClass(this);
```

By doing that, you can get the main Window object.
So now, you can close your Window object as follows:

```
// in YourPageClass code

private void closebt_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (main != null)
    {
        main.Exitbt_PreviewKeyDown(main.Exitbt, e);
        main.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working because it's not enter into IF condition, what is the value into main object so not be null ?

Comment: Why the main object contain null ? and what is the value into main object so not be null?

Comment: I'm sorry but I supposed that the type of your main Window object is MainWindow, so I tried to cast `Application.Current.MainWindow` as `MainWindow`. If you really need to create new MainWindow object, you can add `main.Close();` after `main.Exitbt_PreviewKeyDown(main.Exitbt, e);` in your code.

Comment: I don't need to create to new MainWindow object, i want to get to current instance but, what is the value into object so not be null?

Comment: About `as` operator, you can check [this MS Developer Network document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx).

Comment: Ok but What to do in order to get  current instance or i fill it to value so execute this?

Comment: [`Application.Current.MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) property returns the main window object of the application. I thought it's the same with MainWindow because of your code. Please try to set breakpoint at the `MainWindow main = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;` line and inspect the property's value.

Comment: It' working now Thanks for your help and sorry if i was take much of your time