# Closing a page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C#, I just created a new page and want to close it in the XAML side I have:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Back" Click="Button_Click_Exit"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,263,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for calibrationPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class calibrationPage : Page
    {
        public calibrationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_Exit(object sender,
            RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I think this supposed to be really simple, somehow I get this error, when I try to build it:

```
error CS1061: 'UI.calibrationPage' does not contain a definition for 'Close'
and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument
of type 'UI.calibrationPage' could be found
```

**Edit 1:** I understand that `close()` does not exit, then rephrasing my question, how can I simply close the page using a button click?

**Edit 2:** For the benefit of others: I ended up using `PageNavigator.NavigateTo` function to navigate back and forth between pages, I do not think that there is a concept of closing one page in WPF. Thanks for everyone's participation.

Comment: There is not a Close() method. It is trying to use it , but it cannot find its implementation.

Comment: The error says it all. There is no close method for a page. The parent which could be a window or any application will have a close method.

Comment: @Versatile I understand. So how can I close the page!!!

Comment: So that should be your title to this question. :)

Comment: So where does this page reside into. Can you let us know the control hierarchy that you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling an object to close.

If you're just wanting a button to act on the event, I'd recommend click event or `OnClick`. If you are in VS you can just double click the button in the designer, it will auto populate everything for you.

If you want a form to close you can use similar methods from your WPF window.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to create your own method (like in this case) you can do so like:

```
private void closeMethod()
{
   // your code here
}
```

Then you call it with:

```
closeMethod();
```

Depending on your method you can tell it to do what you want on the page. Such as close the page or window.

You can also pass references in your methods

Refer to: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) for methods.

Not sure if it fits here, but you may want to use `Application.Exit();` in some cases, if so refer to: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f23247b8-e0ca-46eb-afb0-dbf22d4c84ac/thisclose-vs-applicationexit?forum=winforms) to find the difference.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I did, check the xaml there is Click="Button_Click_Exit" is this enough?

Comment: What is your end goal for the button? Just getting it to close?

Comment: Let me ask a more clear question. Are you trying to close the page from within the WPF application? What is the button actually supposed to do? I can probably help you a little more knowing that.

Comment: Pages are generally hosted in Frames inside Windows.

Page does not have a Close method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx)

Perhaps you want to be using Window instead?

Comment: @apc is correct. I edited my answer a little bit to be a little more clear.

Comment: @Mokey clearly, I just want to simply close the page.

Comment: maybe this link will help you more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708309/close-page-within-frame-in-a-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You would think closing a page would be a trivial task, but there's no page.Close property so what is one to do?  I don't think pages were designed to be opened and closed like Windows, but here's a solution that should solve the problem for most.

To start, create a new WPF application and add a page to it called Page1.

In MainWindow.xaml, create a grid with a button and frame to display your page.  (The frame is a key element because you can close the page by setting the frame.content = Nothing)

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
...
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button Content="Page1" Click="Page1_Click" Height="40"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="mainframe" Margin="0,50,0,0" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.vb, add this code to display the page within the frame...

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Page1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim page1 As New Page1(mainframe)
        mainframe.Content = page1
    End Sub
End Class
```

In Page1.xaml, create a grid with a button to close the page...

```
<Page x:Class="Page1">
    ...
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Page1Button_Click" Content="Close Page 1" Height="140" Width="140"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And in your Page1.xaml.vb, close the page like this...

```
Class Page1
    Private mainwin_frame As Frame

    Public Sub New(localframe As Frame)
        InitializeComponent()
        mainwin_frame = localframe
    End Sub

    Private Sub Page1Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        mainwin_frame.Content = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

The key to all of this working is passing the mainframe object to the Page1 constructor so the page can access it.  I'm sure there are other ways to do this but this is a common sense approach imo.